# Macbook incorrectly sets date time based on my location

Tags: macos, ventura, timezone

I've recently upgraded to Ventura and found that the system date time is incorrect. I've checked the Date Time settings that shows:

[image]

I'm located in CET, but it incorrectly sets it up to PST and my closest city Cupertino, while I'm in Spain.

Location services are enabled:

[image]

My Region settings:

[image]

Why isn't it detecting my actual location?

As a workaround I tried to set it up manually, but it doesn't allow to choose a different timezone:

[image]

Comment: Check your external IP address, using Google or directly with https://www.whatsmyip.org then search 'who is [ip address]' This should give you a geolocate on that address, allowing you to check where the error is. My ISP once changed their IP address ranges & everything thought I lived 400 miles away for a month.

Comment: It seems to be ok, my external IP is located in Spain.

Comment: Have you done the restart as it says it will be updating time zone definitions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I finally found a solution. There's something strange here, this functionality doesn't work as one expects and there's kind of a usability problem:

1. This is incorrect, my current location isn't correctly detected:

[image]

2. I had to disable the automation. Opening the combobox there are some predefined locations:

[image]

3. However... the combobox is also a text input, and there I could set a city close to my location. The timezone is automatically updated to the right one:

[image]

4. I can reenable the automatic detection and it keeps my configuration:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has already been answered but it didn't work for me. [This answer from Apple Support](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254633043?answerId=258650681022#258650681022) is what worked for me.
Here is a breakdown of the answer:
For this question, we'll be using the terminal.

1. In your terminal, use the below command to find out the  timezones that are available. Go through the different timezones and find yours

```
sudo systemsetup -listtimezones | more
```

[image: list of timezones on Mac]

2. Next, set your timezone to the one you want. In this example, I'll be setting the timezone to `Africa/Abidjan`

```
sudo systemsetup -settimezone Africa/Abidjan
```

3. Verify that you have set the timezone correctly

```
sudo systemsetup -gettimezone
```